# Shoes with no laces?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In a recent tweet, a former Democratic ethics adviser had some less than flattering comments for the current president (as is the norm in Washington.) When discussing the investigation, he said,

> Kushner, Donnie Jr. and the rest of the Trump crime family better keep their overnight bags handy. **Pack shoes with no laces guys.**

What does it mean to pack shoes with no laces, and what is the implication here? It must be some colloquial phrase, but exactly what it implies I don't understand.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about an interpretation of a witticism based upon localised cultural mores, not about a standard expression.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm afraid it is common parlance. It just depends on what company you keep.

Comment: @Nigel J 620 Google hits for "Pack shoes with no laces" and 'common parlance' don't match up. (If there were say 100 000 hits, I'd have obviously got the close-vote reason wrong: it should have been 'lack of reasonable research'.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think it is not the kind of expression that will figure greatly in recorded literature. It is 'street-speak', which is quite legitimate - in my own view. It is English and it is spoken.

Comment: Velcro, duh ... oh. That's called buy-some-new-shoelaces-time because getting them back in without the plastic tips is impossible and they're gross anyway... or so I've heard.

Comment: @Nigel J Whereas I agree with Matt Gutting about the requirements of ELU: 'What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer; one that you can support with authoritative references.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I couldn't agree more.It would seem that my answer answer is being strongly supported.

Comment: @Nigel J You agree that there should be authoritative references in a good answer? Or was 'I couldn't agree more' ill chosen? / I would have thought that most people would have seen the inadequacies of the voting system of late.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Now you've lost me completely.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The quote mentions :

> the 'Trump **crime** family'.
>
> [I am quoting, not agreeing or commenting.]

When one is placed in a holding cell, one's laces are removed from one's shoes. This is to prevent suicide. Persons unused to cell conditions can easily fall prey to depression.

So 'pack shoes with no laces' means 'you're going to jail'.

> Sergeant Carville said when he joined the force 17 years ago it was the practice to remove a prisoner's laces but over a period of time this was changed to the discretion of duty officers in some stations.
>
> "It was felt removing shoes and laces affected the dignity of the prisoner, but they were taken away if it was thought the person might use them to endanger themselves," he said.

[Herald Scotland](http://www.heraldscotland.com/news/12043236.Prisoner_used_shoelace_to_hang_himself/)

---

Comment: The remark is, in English English, a witticism.  An American would, I think, call it a wisecrack.  In either version of English, it is clever.  Thank you for making me smile.

Answer (score -1):

"Pack shoes without laces" when taken in context with "Better keep overnight bags handy" means be ready to leave quickly.

Laceless shoes just need to be slipped on while the lacey kind require time to lace up.

Comment: I assume "overnight bags" is a reference to bags of personal belongings to take to prison. See e.g. http://prisonuk.blogspot.com/2014/10/off-to-prison-my-packing-list.html, http://www.devonlive.com/news/uk-world-news/going-jail-what-you-should-400720, https://books.google.com/books?id=Du0jBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT101&lpg=PT101&dq=overnight+bag+prison&source=bl&ots=Y4n8mZZ5Ol&sig=DCg_uH-OMO17R9DS_2SrqDsIKKo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-77mKt-TXAhWj7YMKHau8Bs4Q6AEIVzAM#v=onepage&q=overnight%20bag%20prison&f=false I don't get the impression that people need to hurry to put on their shoes in this context.

Comment: @sumelic: You wrote "I assume "overnight bags" is a reference to bags of personal belongings to take to prison." Yes, in the specific context of the OP's quote, but your assumption doesn't apply more generally, because "overnight bags" is not understood in general usage to be specifically for prison. My comment was to emphasise the general meaning of overnight bags - i.e. preparation for an unplanned period away from home - which Hussain Akbar had then misapplied in the context of laceless shoes (being a very specific reference to entering prison). If I've misread your assumption, I apologise.

Comment: @Chappo: ah, thanks for the clarification. I didn't mean to imply that "overnight bags" always refers to bags to take to prison; just that it did in the case of this particular tweet. I agree with you about its general meaning in most contexts

Comment: @Chappo Must be a cultural nuance. Where I am, shoes with laces implies a person who takes care in dressing and/or formal shoes while laceless shoes are semi-formal / casual, neither implies incarceration. For such a case, we would say "slippers" as those are prison footwear.

Comment: Hussein, see Nigel J’s answer. Shoes with laces are probably universally regarded as more formal, sophisticated and stylish. The point is, don’t wear nice shoes (with laces) if you expect to go to jail.,